# Is the CLR a virtual machine?

Tags: .net, clr, vm-implementation

I read a book which referred to the .net **CLR as a virtual machine**? Can anyone justify this? What is the reason we need the concept of virtual machines on some development platforms?

Isn't it possible to develop a native framework [one without virtual machine] that is fully object oriented and as powerful as .net?

The book which refers to CLR as virtual machine is "**Professional .Net Framework 2.0**".

Comment: This is really just an argument over what a "virtual machine" is. Note that the "native" x86 instruction set can be viewed as a virtual machine instruction set, interpreted by the CPU.  So if the CLR runs on top of a virtual machine, is it possible for it to not be considered a virtual machine as well?

Comment: The CLR does not run on top of a "virtual machine".  The CLR is a just-in-time compiler and a garbage collector.  When the CLR needs to invoke into a C library it doesn't have the overhead that JNI does because it is already native code, meaning all it has to do is push the arguments onto the stack and jump to the method.  Whereas Java has to do all sorts of expensive gymnastics to make that scenario work, resulting in a very slow bridge to native code.

Comment: @hoodaticus: .NET works just fine inside VMware, VirtualBox, Virtual PC, etc, so I don't know why you make a universal claim that it does not run on VMs.  But I guess you meant whether CLR is itself a VM, not whether it runs on top of one.  As you say, the CLR has a JIT compiler and a garbage collector.  But you missed the verifier.  And the security model.  And its own implementation of threads distinct from the OS.  And its own loader.  And runtime introspection, including a sophisticated debug API.  It certainly is a virtual machine.

Comment: It chooses to share a lot of things with the physical machine, such as address space (which is virtualized on the physical machine anyway), in order to reduce the amount of work that p/invoke has to do.... but depending on the types involved p/invoke does quite a lot of work, and even for simple types it is nowhere near as simple as "push the arguments onto the stack and jump".  Every managed/native transition involves changing garbage collector state, to pin parameters passed by reference and also to allow the GC to pause the thread upon return to managed code.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - yes, if you add a bunch of work I never specified then there is more work to be done for the native call, but if you use only blittable types the difference between the CLR and Java becomes readily apparent.  Not counting pushing the arguments onto the stack, a calli instruction compiles to like 6 ASM instructions.  I seriously doubt an interpreted Java method can do it anywhere near as efficiently.  The interpretation is what makes a running Java method "virtual" while a running CLR method is as real as any compiled C++ method.

Comment: @hoodaticus: But I didn't "add" it, the CLR always does those things and you chose to leave them out of your implementation to support your description of a very thin layer.  But code running with the CLR is "managed" not "native", and managed/native transitions are complicated beasts.  Even if a lot of the work is done using table lookups (the same sort of approach as zero-overhead exception handling) so that it doesn't appear at the call site, the fact remains that every one of those transitions has the potential to be a synchronization point with the garbage collector.

Answer (score 112):

There are a lot of misconceptions here.  I suppose you could think of .Net as a virtual machine if you really wanted, but let's look at how the .Net Framework really handles your code.  The typical scenario looks like this

1. You write a .Net program in C#, VB.Net, F#, or some other compatible language.
2. That code is compiled down to an Intermediate Language (IL), which is similar to Java's bytecode, that is distributed to end-user machines.
3. An end user invokes the program for the first time on a computer with the right version of .Net installed
4. The computer sees this is a .Net assembly rather than "raw" machine code, and passes it off to the JIT compiler
5. The JIT compiler *compiles the IL to fully-native machine code*.
6. The native code is saved in memory for the life of this program execution.
7. The saved native code is invoked, and the IL no longer matters.

There are a couple important points here, but the big one is that at no point is any code ever interpreted.  Instead, you can see in step 5 that it is compiled to native code.  This a *huge* difference than loading it into a virtual machine, for several reasons:

1. The fully-compiled code is executed by the cpu directly rather than interpreted or translated by an additional software abstraction layer, which should be faster.
2. The JIT compiler can take advantage of optimizations specific to the individual machine running the program, rather than settling for a lowest common denominator.
3. If you want you can even pre-compile the code and in essence hide step 5 from the user completely.

I suppose you could call this a virtual machine, in the sense the JITter abstracts away the details of the real machine from the developer. Personally I don't think that's really right, because for many people, a virtual machine implies a runtime abstraction away from native code that for .Net programs just *doesn't exist.*

One other key point about this whole process that really sets it apart from a "virtual machine" environment is that it's only the *typical* process. If you really want to, you can pre-compile a .Net assembly before distribution and deploy native code directly to end users (hint: it's slower in aggregate over the life of the program, because you lose machine-specific optimizations). Of course, you still need the .Net runtime installed, but at this point it's really not much different from any other runtime API; it's more like a collection dlls with a nice API you can link against, as you might have with the VB or C runtimes Microsoft also ships with Visual Studio. This kind of takes the IL out of the picture, making the VM moniker much harder to justify. (I say "kind of" because the IL is still deployed and used to verify the saved code, but it's never itself touched for execution).

One other telling point is the lack of a VM process. When you run your app, there's no common "sandbox" process that runs. Compare this with Java, where if you open the task manager when a program is running you will see a process specifically for the Java VM, and the application's actual process is a thread inside of the sandbox created by the VM. In .Net, you see the application's process in the Windows task manager directly.

In summary: you could say that IL + CLR + JIT together somehow make up a virtual machine.  Personally I don't think so, but I won't argue with you if you believe that. The point I want to make is that when you tell someone that .Net runs in a virtual machine with no further explanation, the idea you are communicating to that person is "interpreted bytecode in a host process."  And that's just wrong.

---

**Update** This answer is kind of old now, and things have changed to make .Net even less like a virtual machine. In the era of containers, cold start times can mattter a lot more, and my understanding is recent versions of .Net Core have more tools to make deploying native code — and skipping the JIT step on each startup — even easier.

Comment: Have you got a reference on item 3 from your second list? I've never seen anything that says that pre-JITted code is saved, except when NGEN has been invoked.

Comment: Also, explain the need for Constraint Execution Regions if the JITting all happens once and only once... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228973.aspx

Comment: JITted code is saved in memory, so is lost when  the app exists. The code is re-JITted the next time the app is run (or, more specifically, when a new process uses the code).

Comment: @prokiner - I agree, this is my understanding also

Comment: You seem to be saying that if it doesn't do everything exactly the same way as Java does, then it's not a Virtual Machine. I think that's the biggest thing I disagree with you about, because it then tends to be a circular definition.

Comment: Joel, according to your comments I have the feeling that you believe that the JIT compiler compiles once and for all the IL code to native code when the application starts, then suddenly stops. It's just wrong, the JIT compiles methods on the fly whenever the execution flow requires it. Also, there's a VM process. That's the CLR that is running your application. It's definitely a sandboxed environment, with a GC, a security model, a metadata service. The running application is just named after the .exe because Window's PE loader knows how to delegate to the CLR .net binaries.

Comment: Also, NGEN generated code runs inside a CLR - it doesn't create a native executable that uses CLR/.NET as a "collection (of) dlls with a nice API you can link against" - it just saves off the native code that would be generated by the JIT.

Comment: @Jb, I did believe that, yes.  Further investigation shows it's only true if you use ngen _or_ if you install the assembly to the GAC.  Where I'm at, we end up putting most things into the GAC and so this hasn't been very off, but I realize it's not true for everyone and so I'll update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Damien: no, I don't think it needs to do everything the same as Java to be a VM, but I do have certain expectations when I hear the term "VM" for this context that .Net just does not live up to.  I think it's misleading to tell others that .Net runs "inside" a VM, especially as this is typically used to make a distinction from native code that for .Net does not exist. _IF_ there a VM involved (something I already admitted you could make a case for), it's only from a pre-processing standpoint and not something your code runs "inside".

Comment: @Nate: I mostly agree with you, and that statement should be "it's _like_ a collection of dlls..."  It's supposed to be an abstraction: a simple way to think of it. Will fix.  I disagree, though, that any thing ever runs "inside" the CLR.  "On top of" would be more correct.

Comment: @Joel, still your whole last paragraph is wrong. Windows' PE loader starts the CLR, which itself starts the program within its control, memory and security wise. Inside is definitely usable. That's just a hack to avoid a launcher à la java, Rotor or mono. But the .net EE (execution engine) controls how the program runs.

Comment: Yep. The PE Header redirection is a trick to bootstrap the CLR (mscoree) which is, by all means, running your .Net application.
Moreover, like JB said, JIT is not done once and for all, and some JITted methods can even be discarded and rejitted at a later point.
I guess that misconceptions are in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: Joel, your answer is following the MS lead.  The .net CLR is the evolution of the discontinued JVM.  "IL + CLR + JIT" do equal a VM when the function of the JIT output is to replicate the CLR functionality.  I don't appreciate your strange attack on a well-answered question, including making a bunch of assertions re: my answer that have not yet been answered and appear to be "wrong" on your part.  The OP considers the JVM a VM, so the .Net CLR is also a VM.  Either neither or both of them are Virtual Machines, because not only are they functionally identical, one derives from the other.

Comment: You make point (1) about JIT code being "faster" due to not being interpreted further.  While this is true, it is a little misleading.  The performance of the code is closer to VM performance than, e.g., typical C projects.  The discrepancy is that the JIT output contains many more runtime checks, type-safety checks, and especially many more dynamic allocations than a typical C project.  My comparison is not intended to be a value comparison, but rather on this angle: JIT output performs like VM code and not like code written to the non-VM API, both speed and security-wise.  It's like a VM.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Regarding #3, this reference indicates that only NGEN'd code is saved: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163655.aspx "Note the subtle tradeoff here. Using NGEN means trading CPU consumption for more disk access, since the native image generated by NGEN is likely to be larger than the MSIL image. You might be wondering if this could hurt cold startup as it results in increased disk activity. Interestingly, the CLR Performance team has observed that if JIT compilation is completely eliminated, cold startup time typically improves."

Comment: By "discontinued JVM" I mean the discontinued Microsoft Java Virtual Machine.

Comment: "the idea you are communicating to that person is "interpreted bytecode in a host process." And that's just wrong". I couldn't agree more. That is not, in my view, the definition of a Virtual Machine.

Comment: You write "I think the most telling thing, though, is the lack of a VM process" <-- Well, according to http://linuxpoison.blogspot.co.uk/2010/11/how-to-compile-and-run-c-net.html   To compile `gmcs hello.cs` and here's the kicker, to run `mono hello.exe`  that looks like a process running it to me

Comment: Hmm, you can load a .Net DLL in a native process.  I can write an exe in Raw Assembly for X86, that invokes the .Net CLR and causes it to load in my native assembly EXE, then I can take that further and load .Net DLLs into that process once the CLR is loaded, and in this way I have a native process running .Net code.

You can also write Native win32 dll's and exe's in C++ in Mixed CLR mode.  You can write a C++ dll that has an EAT with exported native functions, and a .Net referencable DLL in one DLL.  One dll you can use GetProcAddress on, and reference in .Net code.

Comment: The .net framework is just a library, written natively in C/C++.  Then an addition to PE Format was made to set whether a dll or exe is .Net code or not and contains MSIL.

The windows loader does indeed JIT compile all running code into native machine code when it loads it.  The only thing it does on demand is code that wasn't being referenced.  E.g. if code loads another DLL later down the pipe as a result of a user action or something, then that will get JIT compiled on demand.

Now .Net Native is out, and with that you can compile your code and the .Net parts it uses to native code.

Answer (score 34):

Similar to the Java Virtual Machine (JVM), the .net CLR is a byte-code interpreting virtual machine.

The JVM interprets programs which contain java byte codes and the .net CLR interprets programs which contain what Microsoft calls "Intermediate Language (IL)" instructions.  There are differences between these byte codes, but the virtual machines are similar and aspire to provide similar features.

Both of these virtual machine implementations have the ability to compile their input bytecode to the machine language of the computer they are running on.  This is called *"Just In Time Compilation (JIT)"* and the output code produced is called "JIT code."  Because the JIT code contain sequences of instructions in the machine language of the computer's CPU, this code is sometimes referred to as "native" code.

However, JIT code is qualitatively and quantitatively different from native code, as explained below.  For that reason, this article considers JIT code to be nothing more than a *native implementation of the Virtual Machine while running a particular bytecode program*.

One feature that both these Virtual Machines (VMs) aspire to provide is security in the form of preventing certain hazardous programming errors.  For example, the title of this website forum, stackoverflow, is inspired by one such type of hazardous error that is possible in native code.

In order to provide safety and execution security, the VMs implement type safety at the "Virtual Machine level".  Assignments to VM memory are required to store the type of data which is held in that memory location.  For example, if an integer is pushed onto the stack, it is not possible to pop a double from the stack.  C-style "unions" are prohibited.  Pointers and direct access to memory are prohibited.

We could not get the same benefits by enforcing an object oriented language framework on developers if the result is a native binary such as an EXE file.  In that case, we would not be able to distinguish between native binaries generated using the framework and EXEs generated by a malicious user employing sources other than the framework.

In the case of the VMs, the type-safety is enforced at the "lowest level" that the programmer is allowed to access.  (Neglecting for a moment that it is possible to write managed native code, that is.)  Therefore, no user will encounter an application which performs one of the hazardous operations which require direct access to memory locations and pointers.

In practice, the .net CLR implements a way to write native code which can be called by .net "managed" code.  In this case, the burden is on the native code author not to make any of the pointer and memory mistakes.

As both the JVM and .net CLR perform JIT compilation, either VM actually creates a native-compiled binary from the bytecode supplied.  This "JIT code" performs more quickly than the VM's interpreter execution, because even the machine language code produced by JIT contains all the VM's needed safety checks that the VM would perform.  As a result, the JIT output code is not as fast as native code which would ordinarily not contain numerous run-time checks.  However, this speed performance drawback is exchanged for an improvement to reliability including security; in particular, use of uninitialized storage is prevented, type-safety of assignments is enforced, range-checking is performed (thus stack- and heap- based buffer overflows prevented), object lifetimes are managed by garbage collection, dynamic allocation is type safe.  An environment executing such run-time behavior checks is implementing the specification of a virtual machine and is little more than a machine language realization of a virtual machine.

Comment: Solid detailed informative answer but I hope you won't mind if I pick one nit.  A stack overflow is absolutely possible in managed code: to reproduce this, create and call the following method: public void f() { f(); }.  The difference tends to be that errors are more predictable and less exploitable (this ties in with type safety, one effect of which is to prevent data being accidentally run as code).  For example dereferencing a bad pointer in C has unpredictable results; but dereferencing null on the JVM or CLR safely and predictably gives you an exception.  Apologies for pedantry!

Comment: That is a different kind of stack overflow, but I see what you mean. I was referring to the overflow of a stack buffer, not exhaustion of the stack itself. I think the name of this website also refers to the former and not the latter, but that could just be my perspective. Typically, stack-based buffer overflows are much more interesting than exhaustion of the stack (or of the VM stack), so that's usually what people mean when they write "stack overflow" although technically your interpretation could also be correct.  But thanks for the comment.  ;)

Comment: This is just wrong.  .Net languages are compiled to IL, which is similar to java byte code, and it's the IL that is distributed to user computers for execution.  The difference is that instead of loading bytecode into a VM for execution, .Net IL is compiled to native code before execution.  No virtual machine as such is ever loaded.

Comment: @Joel - surely it's compilation to native code is an irrelevant detail? A future version of the CLR that had a lightning fast interpreter could switch to interpretation instead, and no-one would need to know that fact...

Comment: @Damien: you could say the same thing about java switching to a native compiled mode. If they did that, you'd see a lot of marketing noise about "losing the VM".  Plus, .Net gives you the option to pre-compile if you really want it (hint: it's slower on average over the life of a program), which kinda takes the IL out of the picture.

Comment: @Joel - I don't think you would. Developers still would target the Virtual Machine. I guess we're working from different definitions of Virtual Machine, but to my mind such details as JIT compilation are irrelevant.

Comment: Another difference: the JIT stops running _before_ your program starts.  People tend to think of VM like a sandbox for you code, and with .Net there is no sandbox environment running while your code does.

Comment: @Joel - Just a bit of clarification... JITting is at the method level, so each method gets compiled right before it is called the first time. So technically, the JITter is called throughout program execution, each time a previously-uncalled method is invoked. The only time that the JITter would be "shut down" is if every method and type in your code has already been accessed once.

Comment: The JVM does something similar - it natively compiles "heavily used" code segments rather than all the code - http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/perf2.html - search for "Adaptive optimization" "Just-In-Time Compilers"

Comment: Joel: WHAT?  Of course the IL is what's distributed to users and then JITed, same as JVM bytecode.  In fact, that's my point -- it's functionally on-par (by design) to JVM bytecode.  In fact, Sun Java had JIT prior to MS JVM, IIRC.  Both had it before CLR existed.  Remember MS JVM?

Comment: "That is, on the computer which is running the 'interpreted' code, the VM actual creates a native-compiled binary from the bytecode supplied. "  VM = CLR, bytecode=IL, supplied="Sent to user"

Comment: The first sentence is wrong.  IL is never interpreted, only compiled.  That Java also has a JIT does not change the fact that Java is specified in terms of an interpreter, and .NET is specified in terms of a compiler.

Comment: Also Joel's comment "with .Net there is no sandbox environment running while your code does." is totally wrong.

Comment: @BenVoigt But when the CLR isn't using JIT, isn't it interpreting?  If not then what is it doing?

Comment: @barlop: No, it has no interpreter logic at all.  What functions in the CLR do besides JITting depends on the function -- the behavior is determined by the called function, and not by the application code.  (An interpreter is a library of functions whose behavior depends on the application code loaded into it)

Comment: @BenVoigt  For bytecode to run, if there's no interpreting to native machine code at all, it has to be all compiled to native machine code. If only some code is JITd, then the rest would have to be compiled some other way. What would you call the compilation of the code that is not JITd? AOTd? Or is all the code JITd?  The CLR calls  the JIT compiler so it can't be an AOT compiler. I suppose the entire bytecode is JITd then?

Comment: @barlop: Yes, all the bytecode is JITted before it runs.  That's not a single step, though.  The JIT compiler really does run "just in time".  I'm not sure exactly how that works, but you could think that a function pointer starts out with the address of the compiler function itself.  The first time it's called, the compiler produces the machine code, and changes the pointer so the next call goes direction to the machine code.

Comment: @Ben Voigt - yes, a pre-jitted method contains a jump to its own compilation, the last steps of which are to replace this "pre-JIT stub" with the method body, push the arguments onto the stack, and then jump to it.

Answer (score 10):

The "Virtual Machine" part refers to the fact that .NET code is compiled into EXE's and DLL's as "Intermediate" Assembly language (IL) to run on a virtual machine, as opposed to real CPU assembly language.  Then, at runtime the ILM is converted into real CPU assembly for execution (referred to as Just-in-time, or JIT compiling).

Sure, you could write a .NET compiler so that it would be compiled into CPU assembly language instead of IL.  However, this would not be portable to all CPUs - you'd have to to compile a different version for each OS/CPU pair.  But by compiling into ILM, you let the "Virtual Machine" handle the CPU and OS specific stuff.

Comment: I think you mean IL, or more correctly CIL - Common Intermediate Language.

Answer (score 3):

Neither the JVM nor the CLR do anything that is materially different than what most "virtual machines" for other languages also do.  Modernly, they all use JIT to convert virtual instructions (p-code, bytecodes, intermediate language instructions, call it whatever you like) to "native CPU hardware" instructions ("machine code.")

In fact, the first "virtual machine" to do this was the Smalltalk virtual machine. The author of that innovation, Peter Deutsch, dubbed it "dynamic translation" instead of the term "JIT," which was popularized by Java.  If the Smalltalk "runtime execution environment" is going to be called a "virtual machine" (and that's what it's still called,) then any and all other "run time systems" that do essentially the same thing also qualify as "virtual machines."

Comment: The JVM also uses an interpreter to run code; it is not a pure compilation model like desktop .NET's CLR.  It's materially different because .NET intermediate language is designed with the assumption of JIT compilation -- while one could write an interpreter, the performance would be bad, much worse than the Java interpreter, where the bytecode format is optimized for interpretation.

Comment: But yes, it is still a virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage of the CLR is the freedom to write code in whatever programming language the developer chooses, since the code will be compiled down to CLR before being interpreted into native calls. The .NET framework uses this JIT compilation to treat everything uniformly and output programs which work for the platform being deployed on, which is absent from compiled languages.

Comment: How is it wrong? The VM translates CLR byte code into native CPU instructions, does it not?

Comment: Your comment is right: it compiles (translates) CLR bytecode, called "Intermediate Language" into native machine code.  That's not *interpreting*.  In interpretation, the program is data; the code of the runtime tests conditions on the data and jumps to other code within the runtime; the processor instruction pointer only traverses code which exists within the runtime.  In compilation, the program is turned into a code section which is executed on the processor (the runtime library code still runs when called by the compiled program code, but not all code pre-exists in the runtime).

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit old school, so i call the CLR a virtual machine as well. My reasoning is that the CLR assembles the machine code from an intermediate bytecode, which is what a virtual machine also does.

The benefits of the CLR is mainly due to the way it assembles the machine code which utilizes runtime type information.

You can develop a native framework as powerful as the .NET framework using just native types. The only flexibility you lose is the ability to reassemble the native code if you ever transport your program to another platform without recompiling.

Comment: Creating machine-targeted instructions from an intermediate representation is called compilation where I come from.

Answer (score 1):

You've got many valuable answers, but I think one thing hasn't been mentioned yet: Modularity.

It's quite hard to export a OO class from native DLL. Sure, you can tell the linker to export the class and import it somewhere else, but this is brittle; Changing a single private member in a class will break binary compatibility, i.e. if you change one DLL without recompiling all the other modules, your program will crash horribly at runtime.

There are some ways around this: For example, you can define public abstract interfaces, derive from those and export global factory functions from your DLL. That way, you can change implementation details of a class. But you can't derive from that class in another DLL. And changing the interface also breaks binary compatibility, of course.

I'm not sure if there is a good solution for this in native code: If the compiler/linker creates native code at compile time, then it must know the exact memory layout of the classes/structures that are used in code. If the last compilation step (generating native code) is delayed until a method is called for the first time, this problem simply goes away: you can modify a class in an assembly, and as long as the JIT can resolve all the used members *at runtime*, everything will run fine.

In a nutshell: If you create a monolithic single-executable program, you could probably have most of the powerful features of .NET with a compiler that creates native code. But the disadvantages of having a JIT compiler (framework installation, slightly longer startup times) really don't outweigh the benefits in most cases.